# Problem Installing Lion on MacBook2,1 using USB

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, upgrade, startup

I have a `Macbook2,1` with `4GB RAM`, `Intel Core 2 Duo 2GHz` and `Leopard 10.5.8` and I need to upgrade it to `Lion`. I've downloaded Lion installation dmg file and restored it to a USB disk using `Disk Utility`.

But when I restart my MacBook holding option key, it doesn't show the USB disk. it only shows my hard disk. I've tried an external DVD-Drive (since the original DVD-Drive is not functional), same problem. Also I've tried restarting through Startup Disk preferences, same problem.

Any idea?

Comment: What model/year MacBook are you using?

Comment: That's [Target Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1661), and, apparently, it's entering it as its unable to access the USB. So there's, probably, an issue either with the USB image or the compatibility between your computer and the new OS.

Comment: @Bizz Can you test that the USB was properly created? Is it properly formatted? Can you try to boot from it from another computer? Does it mounts on the desktop?

Comment: it mounts on desktop. It doesn't show up in Startup Disk pref, until I remove and insert it. But Disk Utility recognizes it and Disk Utility->First Aid->Verify was OK.

Comment: Can you post the information that appears at the bottom of Disk Utility when you select your USB disk?

Comment: I Can't right now. Sorry. But I've managed to create a bootable Lion partition from MacBook's own hard disk, and it seems to work, but first I have to make sure :-)

Comment: Can you upgrade directly from 10.5 to 10.7? I thought 10.6 was required to install 10.7.

Comment: I thought that too, but I manually changed the version to 10.6 http://www.macworld.com/article/1167868/how_to_install_mountain_lion_over_leopard.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I finally managed to make it work. It seemed the problem is somehow related to USB boot support of MacBook2,1. This is how it worked for me:

**use these 5 steps if you're `upgrading from 10.5.X to 10.7.X`**

1. Copy `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` to desktop
2. Open it in an editor (I used `TextEdit`)
3. Under `ProductVersion` change `10.5.X` to `10.6.X`
4. Save and Authenticate
5. copy it back to `/System/Library/CoreServices/` overwriting the original `SystemVersion.plist`

---

**use these 8 steps if you have a problem with `USB boot`.**

1. Using `BootCamp` Create a 5GB partition
2. Open `Disk Utility`
3. Select Lion installation file (`DMG`) and click on Open
4. From main pane Click on `Restore` Button
5. From left pane Drag and drop `ESD` (below the DMG) onto `Source`
6. From left pane Drag and drop the `newly create partition` onto `Destination`
7. Click on `Restore` button below Destination
8. Restart and hold `Option` key. Now the partition is available in the boot menu.